# Magit equivalent for "git branch | git branch -d"

Tags: magit

I just learned about `magit-remote-prune` for cleaning up stale remote branch.

For merged local branches, I often use `git branch | git branch -d` to clean up. Is there a way to do that in Magit; conveniently listing merged local branches, and selecting them for deletion?

Answer (score 10):

`git branch` lists *all* local branches as well as `*`, so the command you have given cannot actually be used to delete all merged branches and nothing else. Or if actually does do it while printing some error messages in the process, then I would never-the-less strongly advice against doing that.

Magit does not have a "delete all merged branches" command.

You can however list all branches merged into `master` using `C-u y - M o master RET` (or `C-u y - m` if `master` is checked out). Then you can mark these branches using the region and delete them using `k`.

Comment: Nifty. Can you clarify what the keybinding sequence is when you're on master? `C-u y - m`, and then `c`?

Comment: I'm not getting this to work. The error message I'm getting is that `y - is undefined`.

Comment: `y` is supposed to be bound to `magit-show-refs` but if you use e.g. `evil`, then the binding might be different.